# Elastislide ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, slider

In `Elastislide` responsive slide , when dynamically adding values  through

```
var $items  = $('<li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li><li><a href="#"><img src="images/large/2.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>');
$('#carousel').append($items).elastislide( 'add', $items );
```

It is added in wrong place(after class `es-nav-next`). Is there any workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If we split and give it is working

```
$('#carousel ul').append($items1);
$('#carousel').elastislide( 'add', $items1 );
```